# Некорректно работает slcik slider

Tags: html, css, jquery

Проблема в том что изображение сжимается по высоте до 1px. вот код

```
    <div class="slider__header">
        <div class="slider"><img src="../img/dark__souls3.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="slider"><img src="../img/batman.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="slider"><img src="../img/destiny.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="slider"><img src="../img/prey.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div class="slider"><img src="../img/uncharted4.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </div>

.slider__header {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    .slider {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: А это для чего?  `z-index: -1`

Comment: Для меню, слайдер находится на верху страницы, а на слайдере меню поэтому применил z-index

Comment: почему у шапки не сделать тогда `position: absolute` и ей задать `z-index`?

Answer (score 0):

не понятно зачем вы используете клас .slider

слик сам пропишем Вам все стили

также возможно у вас в стилях где-то ограничены размеры img
увидеть бы в живую очень помогло решить проблему

а так вот стандарный код в вашей ситуации
html

```
<div class="slider__header">
    <div class='item'><img src="../img/dark__souls3.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class='item'><img src="../img/batman.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class='item'><img src="../img/destiny.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class='item'><img src="../img/prey.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class='item'><img src="../img/uncharted4.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.item img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

js

```
$('.slider__header').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

попробуйте так, должно помочь.

также можите через девтулзы залещть и посмотреть изображение и поймёте что с ним не так и что ограничивает

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y5ep7a08/12/
вот код

Answer (score 0):

с Вашего кода удаляешь

```
.slider__header .item {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

и радуешся.
Хотя вобще непонятно зачем вы это туда добавляете.
Вам не надо стилизировать итем, этим займётся сам slickslider

Comment: Это да)
Но мне надо чтобы header был поверх слайдера, то есть где лого сайта, поиск и корзина, я этого пытаюсь добиться

Comment: Все разобрался спасибо!)